# How can I find the most suitable IBMQ provider for my location?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I have been trying to run my code on IBM's quantum computers, so I used the following commands to associate a quantum computer to the component qcomp:

```
provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
qcomp = provider.get_backend('ibmq-16-melbourne')
```

But the queue is endless.
I live in Southern Europe.

Answer (score 2):

All the machines are in New York so it does not matter which one you pick.

Comment: Can you provide me with a list of the available providers?

Comment: You can see these on the IBMQ Experience website